# unable to use the base address of heap in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, arm, heap-memory

I have exported the __heap_base label from the startup file of keil (__heap_base is a label pointing to the starting of heap). In a c file  declared the __heap_base as extern and assigned the address of __heap_base to a void pointer.But this void pointer always has the value 0x00000000 and thus cannot be used to point to the base of heap.
So my indirect question is how to store the base address of heap in a pointer 
and use it as arguments for memory management functions that i may declare and  definie

```
            #include <stdint.h>
            extern  uint32_t __heap_base;
            void* original_heap_base=&__heap_base;
            /*void get_heap_base()
            {
                 original_heap_base=&__heap_base;
            }*/
            void* mem_init()
            {
                void *temp=original_heap_base;
                original_heap_base+=4;
                return temp;
            }       
            int main()
            {
                int *p=(int*)mem_init();
                *p=5;
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: You can't do pointer arithmetic with `void*` pointers.

Comment: Even if i comment out out that line the result is same.

Comment: I never said it was the problem, it's just another issue with your code. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Your code is basically just doing `__heap_base = 5;`. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Basically i want a pointer to base of heap every time.Initially &__heapbase has the address of starting of heap

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1358938929242.htm You define __heap_base if you want to specify it. It isn't defined for you.

Comment: in general, the heap contains a data structure of all the allocated memory segments.  You don't really want to be stepping on the data structure.  I'm not sure what your trying to accomplish, however, I strongly suggest placing data in the 'file global' data area